# The day name showing incorrect value, next day or previous day in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

```
public class Main extends Activity {    
    protected static final int dialog = 0;
    private int Day;
    private int Month;
    private int Year;
    Button mbt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mbt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDialog(dialog);
        }
        });
    }

    private void  UpdateDisplay() {
        String day = (DateFormat.format("EEEEEE", new Date(Year, Month, Day))).toString();
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Year = year;
            Month = monthOfYear;
            Day = dayOfMonth;
            UpdateDisplay();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id) {
            case dialog:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this ,mDateSetListener ,Year , Month , Day);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please some one help me to find out the answer..!!

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: The output shows incorrect day name. if i select a sunday through the date picker by correponding date.. it will toast as Monday.. that means  the next day name.. how this happensa.. anyone help me..!!

Comment: There is no one who can answer this question..??

Comment: Otherwise give me a Android coding for displaying the day name of the particular date by selecting the date through datepicker..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Dedmanding that other people answer your question every 2 minutes isn't going to get you an answer. It will probably just get you ignored and maybe some downvotes. We answer questions here on a volunteer basis, this isn't our job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select a date, Android modifies the date to your own Timezone, you should create a `Calendar` type variable using, `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())` and issue it a `calendar.set(int year, int month, int day)`. Look up http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html if you are unsure about something! :)

Correct code would be:

```
public class Main extends Activity {    
protected static final int dialog = 0;
private int Day;
private Calendar c;
private int Month;
private int Year;

    Button mbt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        c = new Calendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
        mbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mbt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDialog(dialog);
        }
        });
    }

    private void  UpdateDisplay() {
        String day = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Year = year;
            Month = monthOfYear;
            Day = dayOfMonth;
            c.set(Year, Month, Day);
            UpdateDisplay();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id) {
            case dialog:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this ,mDateSetListener ,Year , Month , Day);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: --The method getCurrent() is undefined for the type TimeZone.!!

Comment: Yes, sorry it is `getDefault()`

Comment: Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getCurrent());...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105042/find-out-the-log-value-of-a-number-from-input      please look out my this question also..

Comment: I have already answered that one. If I have solved your problem please, approve my answer.

Comment: i'm not getting any proper answer.. for this day name problem. !! can you please edit my above code with your idea and send it to me please.!

Comment: c = new Calendar(TimeZone.getDefault());  - here Calendar have a red mark. And it says that Cannot instantiate the type Calendar

Comment: Import `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: Yeah.. Thank You Levente Kurusa.!! That was really helpful. :). I got the Output.