# find out the log value of a number from input

Tags: java, android

I have a edittext field for users input. user can enter values up to ten digit number.when clicking on the button, i need to show the log [ mathematics log ] value of that number in double precision.

That i showned below.

If i input xxxxxxxxxx [ consider this as number ]

The output must look like this yy.yy.

```
package com.example.logvalue;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
      EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      final int noo = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
       Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, String.format("%.2f", Math.log10(noo)) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



    }


}
```

Comment: What did you try? why did it fail? care to share your failing code?

Comment: Actually i have no idea how work with the log things.. thasts why i posted this.. can you please give me the just a block of code that can solve the problem.

Comment: when i run this program, it shows that The Application Stopped Working.. why , anyone please help me.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `String.format("%.2f", Math.log10(number))` syntax.
The String class has this format function exactly for these.

I assume you want logarithm with base of 10.

Explanation: `String.format` is the Java-equavalient of the traditional `printf` from C++. The `%` symbol means there is something to be fetched from the argument list, the point means that we want to specify the number of decimals, and hence we put a 2 after that point.
Hope I helped.

Comment: how to get the ten digit number from the input field.??? whats the code for that.?

Comment: This site is not for solving your assignments. Please take a look at the Android API, specifically `EditText`.

Comment: I have answered your question, I would be happy if you accepted it! :)
Also, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: String.format("%.2f", Math.log10(number)) - its ok. but how can i put the input value to it. ??

Comment: Listen, if you don't know this `extremely simple` task, please learn to read a book.
You have an `EditText` field, issue a `getText()` to it, and you will get a `String`, send that to `Integer.parseInt(string)` and there you have that `int`
I have now fully answered your question, please reaccept it.

Comment: i tried it with the following code , u see.. but when i run my program it says that- The Application Stopped Working

Comment: Toast.makeText(Main.this, String.format("%.2f", Math.log10(noo)) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   - here the noo is the int value that i am getting from the edit text field, now please telll me.. whats happening here..???

Comment: replace `noo` with `Integer.parseInt(noo)`
Because I think you have no idea what you are doing.
And that noo is a `String`

Comment: final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       final int noo = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());

Comment: Do you even understand what is `final`?
Remove them immediately.

Comment: Toast.makeText(Main.this, String.format("%.2f", Math.log10(noo)) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); - and thats it.. and i am running the toast thing inside of a button onclick listener.. So tell me now...

Comment: i have to add final for that " noo" value.. other wise it showing error in the toast thing.. inside the listener

Comment: Sir, you have absolutely no idea how computers work. Sorry. Cannot help you anymore. Read some books. Accept my answer, as I have helped you in every way that is possible.

Comment: Anyways. Thank You. its because of  i am a beginner in android. So just leave it that. ok. i'll Accept the Answer.!!

Comment: The things you were asking for were basic Java-only stuff. Not a single Android involved there, except for the `EditText`. Thanks for accepting.